# change position absolute parent

Tags: html, css, position

is there any way to change position absolute parent?

in this example I want to send red box to position right:0 of his second parent (black box)

```css
.box1{
  height:500px;
  width:500px;
  position:relative;
  background:black;
}

.box2{
  height:300px;
  width:300px;
  position:relative;
  background:green;
  
}

.box3{
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  position:absolute;
  background:red;
  right:0
}
```

```html
<div class="box1">
  <div class="box2">
    <div class="box3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: remove position:relative from box2

Comment: @TemaniAfif thank you for your reply ... i know it seems  easy but in my real project i cant remove position relative

Comment: so give us a more realistic code that is close to your real project

Answer (score 0):

Make Some few changes in your markup

```css
.box1 {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  position: relative;
  background: black;
}

.box2 {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  background: green;
}

.box3 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  right: 0
}
```

```html
<div class="box1">
  <div class="box3"></div>
  <div class="box2">
  </div>
```